# How to match ACF and graph?

Tags: r, acf-pacf

[image]

I am reading book called Forecasting principle and practice. here I came across this exercise where i need to match pictures:

answers 1-B, 2-A, 3-D, 4-C my question is how do you see which one belongs to which. what I learned is that if ACF graph is gradually goes down and have a wave like pattern it means seasonality and trend presented, so 3-D is clear but what about others?

Comment: By paying attention to the labels on the horizontal axes, you have already deduced enough to accurately classify the other three plots.

Comment: @whuber can you elaborate?